# Update textfield failed from soap web service result

Tags: swift, web-services, asynchronous, soap

I just started to write app for ios using swift4, and I am stuck here with 2 problems, I am calling a soap web service, it was successful,
and I could print the result(string with xml format)in the output, and I wanted to update the text of one text field with this result,because this task in running in the background, I put the following code in the closure of completionHandler:

```
@IBOutlet weak var txt1: UITextField!

func httpGet(request: URLRequest)-> String{
    let soapReqXML = "some code..."
    let is_URL: String = "http://xxx.x.x.12/soapservice.asmx"
    let url = URL.init(string: is_URL)       
    let my_Request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: url!)            
    let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default                    
    let session = URLSession(configuration: configuration, delegate: self, delegateQueue:OperationQueue.main)

    my_Request.httpMethod = "POST"  
    my_Request.httpBody = soapReqXML.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8, allowLossyConversion: false)
    my_Request.addValue("host add...", forHTTPHeaderField: "Host")
    my_Request.addValue("text/xml;charset =utf-8", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    my_Request.addValue(String(soapReqXML.count), forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Length")
    my_Request.addValue("http://mservice.my.xx/SNA...", forHTTPHeaderField: "SOAPAction")

    var responseData : Data = Data()
    var _re : String = "000"
    let task = session.dataTask(with: my_Request as URLRequest, completionHandler: {data, response, error -> Void in                                            
        if error == nil {               
            responseData = data!                
            _re = self.stringFromXML(data:responseData);   // calling stringFromXML to convert data into string          
            print("the result is :"+_re) // working here, I can see the good result in the output                              
            //execute from the main thread to update txt1
            DispatchQueue.main.async(execute:{
                 self.txt1.text = re // first problem, the error is :Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
                 self.txt1.text = "text" // I even change into "text", same error happened here 
            })    
        }  
    })        
    task.resume()      
    return _re       // second problem, the return is always 000 
}
```

my first problem is :if I call the function in the ipad simulator,in the debug, it's written: txt1=(UITextField!) nil,
 the second problem is, the return is always 000(the initial value)

Can someone help me to check it out?Thanks in advence!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see the output, so re is not nil and therefore txt1 may be nil. Check if txt1 is connected with UITextField in Interface builder.

Second problem is clear. The dataTask in running in the background and therefore func httpGet doesn't wait for dataTask completion and after that continue run code "return _re". Instead of this func performs dataTask and all code after task.resume() (return _re) in parallel way. So the initial value of re remain the same because dataTask need some time for execute completion.

You should use completion handler:

```
func httpGet(request: URLRequest, completion: @escaping (String) -> ()) {
    let soapReqXML = "some code..."
    let is_URL = "http://xxx.x.x.12/soapservice.asmx"
    let url = URL(string: is_URL)
    let my_Request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: url!)
    let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
    let session = URLSession(configuration: configuration, delegate: self, delegateQueue: .main)

    my_Request.httpMethod = "POST"
    my_Request.httpBody = soapReqXML.data(using: .utf8, allowLossyConversion: false)
    my_Request.addValue("host add...", forHTTPHeaderField: "Host")
    my_Request.addValue("text/xml;charset =utf-8", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    my_Request.addValue(String(soapReqXML.count), forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Length")
    my_Request.addValue("http://mservice.my.xx/SNA...", forHTTPHeaderField: "SOAPAction")

    session.dataTask(with: my_Request as URLRequest, completionHandler: { data, response, error in
        if error == nil {
            let result = self.stringFromXML(data: data!)
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.txt1.text = result
            }
            completion(result)
        }
    }).resume()
}
```

Usage:

```
httpGet(request: request) { result in
    print(result)
}
```

Comment: Hi@vlad1278, I checked it,  txt1 is connected with UITextField in Interface builder, and I applied your suggestion to use the completion, and it works very well, and the two problems have been solved at the same time! :) so Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

**First problem:** 

The textfield `txt1` is nil. This can happen if you haven't initialized the view or the view controller from the xib or storyboard properly. If you have outlets (or any customization for that matter) in a xib or storyboard they only get initialized if you use the correct init function. Simply calling the default init will not initialize the outlets.

  To init a view controller of class `MyViewController` from a xib called `MyViewController.xib` that is in the main bundle:

```
let myViewController = MyViewController.init(nibName:"MyViewController", bundle:Bundle.main)
```

To init a view controller of class `MyViewController` that is in and has an identifier `myVC` in `Main.storyboard` that is in the main bundle:

```
if let myViewController = UIStoryboard.init(name:"Main",bundle:Bundle.main).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier:"myVC") as? MyViewController{
 //use the vc
}
```

To init a view of class `MyView` that is customized in a xib 'MyView.xib` that is in the main bundle:

```
if let myView = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("MyView",owner:self)?.first{
 //use your view
}
```

**Second problem:**

The line `return _re` gets executed before the control goes into completion handler where `_re` is getting a new value, because the network call is asynchronous. Hence its returning the initial value. If you want to return some data asynchronously, you should use a completion handler.

```
func httpGet(request: URLRequest,completionHandler:@escaping (String) -> ()){
   let soapReqXML = "some code..."
   let is_URL: String = "http://xxx.x.x.12/soapservice.asmx"
   let url = URL.init(string: is_URL)       
   let my_Request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: url!)            
   let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default                    
   let session = URLSession(configuration: configuration, delegate: self, delegateQueue:OperationQueue.main)

   my_Request.httpMethod = "POST"  
   my_Request.httpBody = soapReqXML.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8, allowLossyConversion: false)
   my_Request.addValue("host add...", forHTTPHeaderField: "Host")
   my_Request.addValue("text/xml;charset =utf-8", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
   my_Request.addValue(String(soapReqXML.count), forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Length")
   my_Request.addValue("http://mservice.my.xx/SNA...", forHTTPHeaderField: "SOAPAction")

   var responseData : Data = Data()
   var _re : String = "000"
   let task = session.dataTask(with: my_Request as URLRequest, completionHandler: {data, response, error -> Void in                                            
       if error == nil {               
           responseData = data!                
           _re = self.stringFromXML(data:responseData);   // calling stringFromXML to convert data into string          
           print("the result is :"+_re)        
           //execute from the main thread to update txt1
           DispatchQueue.main.async(execute:{
                self.txt1.text = _re
           })    
           completionHandler(_re)
       }  
   })        
   task.resume()      
}
```

Comment: actually, I started to use swift4 from last week to test, and I didn't find any xib files in the project folder, maybe it was because I choose the "single view application" when I created the project,  so about the first problem, I did not understand too much from your solution , but I took your second suggestion which is similar to @vlad1278, after that, the two problem just disappeared surprisingly, Thank you very much also!